# Variable name autocomplete for VSCode Language Extension (GameMaker / GML files)?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, game-maker-studio-2, game-maker-language

I'm editing GML files ([GameMaker Studio](https://www.yoyogames.com/en/gamemaker)) in VSCode. There's a wonderful plugin, [GML Support](https://github.com/gml-support/gml-support) which adds autocomplete for inbuilt GML functions and instances variables along with a bunch of other cool things.

However, VSCode doesn't seem to recognise local variables in GML (see screen grab below. Dot notation works fine)

I had a look at the [VSCode's Programmatic Language Extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/overview) for variable name auto-completion but still don't get how I could register the variable declaration (i.e. `var fooBar = 23;`) with VSCode's Language Server.

Ideally, I'd like the Language Server to respect variable scope for GML files:

1. global variables - any `var` declarations for files under `script` folder
2. any local variable declarations - all `var` declarations in the surrounding `{...}`

What would be the easiest way to add variable name completion as described above?

Thanks in advance!

---

**Edit**: looked at [vscode-python](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python) to see how `registerCompletionItemProvider` (based on [VSCode Language Extension doco](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/overview#programmatic-language-features)) could be used. Unfortunately, still not clear to me as vscode-python seem to rely on Jedi to provide symbols?

So any points appreciated!

[image]

Comment: According to https://github.com/gml-support/gml-support/blob/master/src/gml/completionProvider.js#L76, completion for GML either use hard-coded names (for global functions or built-in stuff), or very basic parsing for function names. You would need to add something similar for variable names I guess, but respecting the scope would be much more difficult, you'd probably need a language server for this kind of thing.

Comment: Thanks @holt. Can VSCode be made to just search for `words` used in the current file - which would work for local variables in the current file.  I could just use specific naming convention for global files.

Right now, VSCode is able to `ctrl-space` suggest words I've typed previously in a `plaintext` file, but with `GML Support` extension loaded, that ability seem to have been turned off?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enable simple auto-completion, you can add the following to your `settings.json` (Command Palette ➜ Open Settings (JSON)):

```js
  "[gml-gms81]": { "editor.quickSuggestions": true },
  "[gml-gms1]": { "editor.quickSuggestions": true },
  "[gml-gms2]": { "editor.quickSuggestions": true },
```

which works for a workaround:

[image]

---

For a *proper* solution, well, you'll need to use the `registerCompletionItemProvider` and index the file on demand or as you go.

The [official example](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/main/completions-sample/src/extension.ts#L57) demonstrates the use.

For intricacies of processing GML syntax, you can peck at the [code](https://github.com/YellowAfterlife/GMEdit/blob/d7220fa9586cb24496858e43564250fd99f51dbe/src/parsers/seeker/GmlSeekerProcVar.hx) in the Ace-based external editor that I made. Processing variable definitions specifically requires you to skip over strings, comments, and loop over values (`var name[=value][, name2[=value2]]`) with relative degree of confidence (which can be accomplished through a balanced parser).

Comment: thanks @yellowAfterLife. Unfortunately that the `editor` settings doesn't work once the file type is changed to GML2 which is added by the `gml-support` extension. I did find https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Atishay-Jain.All-Autocomplete which seem to work sometimes - auto completion occasionally conflicts with `gml-support`, but it'll do.

`GMEdit` looks pretty cool. Great work! I gave it a try, but ended up going back to vscode because of git integration. Plus I'm too tied to Vim and VSCode / Sublime shortcuts :p

Comment: Testing further, it seems like the `quickSuggestions` will only pop up once the regular auto-completion menu has no more items to offer, which is either a bug or unfortunate behaviour. As for GMEdit, you can change keybinds and there are predefined options in Code Editor Settings, but there are definitely functionality gaps compared to VSC.